# jQuery doesn't set the css to hide a div directly on pageload in IE

Tags: jquery, css

When switching between pages I would like to show and hide a menu with a jQuery animation.
All is working well when viewing in Firefox, but IE gives a flash of the navigation div before it is hidden by jQuery.
[This is the testpage](http://www.vuyk.eu/testsite/test1/testpage1.html)

Now try navigate between pages with IE and watch the right menu flashing.
Also some other background images are flashing.
I could initially hide it with CSS, but this wouldn't be userfriendly for those who have Javascript turned off.

Can this be resolved in some way?

Comment: In IE8 works the same as in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Please share the code whatever you tried

Comment: Peeyush, thanks for the reply, the code is in the testpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script>
        document.write("<style>.contentToHide {display:none}</style>");
    </script>
    <!-- rest of your styles, javascript, ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contentToHide">This will be hidden on page load - but only if JavaScript is enabled</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked very well, see http://www.vuyk.eu/testsite/test2/testpage1.html
However there's still a flashing of the background

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar scenario. I left the jQuery code as-is, however, I modified the CSS with IE specific codes to set the animated object to `display : none;` on load. You could try something similar to the code as follows:

```
nav {
     display : none\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    *display : none;   /* IE7 and below */  
    _display : none;   /* IE6 */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is a bit like the answer of Andreas.